# Running a second query using the least amount of processing power

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to figure out how to run multiple query using the least amount of processing power in nodejs (this nodejs app is being run in a tablet with not a lot of memory).

Below is the situation (the issue is below the second if statement) :

```
  connection.query("SELECT hashtag from user_information", function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        // Check to see if the user entered hashtag is found in the database
        // Create a variable to track if the item was found
        var wasFound = false;
         for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {


          if (rows[i].hashtag == userEnteredHashtag) {

              res.render('delivery/chooseBox', {
                box_id: 'Box11',
                // Run a second query from box table and grab all of the `longestDimension` of Box11 such as it will come out as 11, 18, 24, etc. and store those numbers in the longestDimension key (increment each instance for example

                longestDimension1: '11',
                longestDimension2: '18',
                longestDimension3: '24',
               )
            });

               // Change the variable to true
               wasFound = true;

    //console.log(packageIdDatabase + 10);
          }

        }
```

Essentially, I would like to  Run a second query from box table and grab all of the `longestDimension` of box_id such as it will come out as 11, 18, 24, and then store those values in the longestDImension key.

Comment: Generally, running a second query is not the most efficient approach. But see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you. What would be the alternative, and even if this is not the most efficient solution what would be the most effective way to use a second query

Comment: I believe I've provided you with steps which, if followed, may allow us to help you answer that.